# Acegen and wsl missing window decoration

Tags: acegen

I'm working with Linux on Windows with wslg (Windows Subsystem Linux). Thus, the linux version of Acegen and Mathematica installed in Ubuntu running in a wsl under Windows 11.
The two problems I'm facing is, that

1. the "main Acegen palette" does not get the usual windows decorations (Minimize/Maximize/Close Button and the window boundary to move the window), so I cannot move the "main Acegen palette"
2. the AceGen operators, the four different "=" operators do not work. They don't insert the corresponding symbol into the main Mathematica window when clicked.

Other windows, like the "Help Browser" or "Messages" get the usual decorations, so I can move and resize them.

See the snapshot below.

Any idea?

[image]